# SQL Server Geography Tables Not Connecting

Tags: qgis

This has me totally confused... it was working last week, isn't working now.

Using QGIS v3.0 and 3.2 and no love. Even tried 2.18.21... no difference.

Follow the pictures...

This is my connection screen, I have used a userid/password and the trusted connection, no difference. I have blurred out what doesn't matter. The database I am connecting to is GIS:

[image: Connection]

When I get to the datamanager, I select MSSQL and then GIS and get this list, with the little whirlly thing... that ever stops... and never presents the one table I need!

[image: Database]

Finally, the table:
[image: The SQL Server 2012 table structure]

This is in SQL Server 2012 R2. I have tried this as both Geometry and Geography... no luck.

If I take out the Place field - the geo point data - I can see the table. Otherwise, it is invisible. It is acting backwards...

Comment: This is taking a turn into the surreal...

I used a different path... added a vector, using MSSQL, and it works. Works great... all my missing tables now magically appear... go figure.

Comment: Oh - if you turn off the option to 'only look in the geometry_columns' table, restart QGIS, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

First, when you query the result table in SQL Server Management Studio, do the POINT features display in the 'Spatial Results' tab? This would show that you have successfully built your geometry/geography objects correctly.

However, the hanging issue is still a potential stopping point.

If you go to the Layer > Add Layer > Add MSSQL Spatial Layer, and connect to your database, you should see a list of all your tables (both GEOMETRY and GEOGRAPHY data types), and click 'Add' to add the table to your map.

There are definitely some issues with the way QGIS reads MSSQL server databases, and the need for the GEOMETRY_COLUMNS tables, etc. becomes important.

While myself and a few others can connect without the issues you're describing above, new QGIS users for some reason get the same hanging behavior - but this seems only to be from the BROWSER panel - the method above seems to always work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... Odd problem, no question. However, when I try to add a layer, select MSSQL Spatial, I see my connection, but no tables with geometry. I tried this again by resetting the field as a geometry vs geography and I get nothing. Same response from QGIS.

Comment: @CorvetteGuru did you try to use MSSQL Server Management Studio to see if the geometry is valid there first?

Comment: Yes, and the spatial data presented just fine.